# Joining Calendar table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, performance

I've created a calendar table (with indexes) that has dates, day of week, fiscal year, day name, etc. The range on my calendar table is between 2005 - 2071. I don't have any issues when I query the calendar table.

I want to use the date column on the calendar table to filter 2 different date columns on 2 different tables.

The issue I'm running into, is when searching a large date range using the date column on the calendar table(i.e. 2010-2019), it's taking a VERY long time to return the results. Whereas, if I query the same date range on each table, the results are returned in seconds. Here's the query i'm working with:

```
Select 
      a.Col1, 
      a.Col2, 
      a.Col3, 
      a.Date1, 
      b.Date1 
   From 
      TableA as A
         FULL JOIN TableB as B 
            on A.Col1 = B.Col1
            INNER JOIN TableCal as C 
               on A.Date1 = C.Date1 
               or B.Date1 = C.Date1
   WHERE 
      C.date1 between '2010' and '2019'
```

If there's a better way to write this or if I'm going about it the wrong way, I'm open to all advice / suggestions! Thanks!

Comment: [Start here on how to get help with a slow query](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/03/getting-help-with-a-slow-query/). Also, although you have already made your own, you may find [Aaron Bertrand's calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) more useful / more dynamic. Also from Aaron, [be sure you really need NOLOCK](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) and understand why it can be a bad idea. It **is not** a "go faster" button.

Comment: First of all, remove those `NOLOCK` hints. They *don't* make anything run faster. Second, does your Calendar table have indexes on its columns? If not, it's going to be slow. Finally, post the *actual* query. What you posted here doesn't join dates and filters the `Date` column by a year string. A calendar table is supposed to have separate fields for each date element and the *date* field should be a `date`. If `WHERE c.date between '2010' and '2019'` doesn't raise an error it's probably because the `date` values were implicitly converted to strings, forcing a full table scan

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  `FULL OUTER JOIN` is rarely needed.

Comment: C.date1 is really a varchar of the year?

Comment: correcting "c.date between '2010' and '2019'" resolved the issue. It looks a  full table scan was causing the delay. Thanks! @PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score 0):

Formally, the answer is to use equijoins, like this:

```
Select a.Col1, a.Col2, a.Col3
From (a join
      cal ca 
      on a.col2 = ca.col2
     ) full join
     (b join
      cal cb
      on b.col2 = cb.col2
     ) 
     on a.col1 = b.col1
where ca.date between '2010' and '2019' or
      cb.date between '2010' and '2019' ;
```